# Wallets for multiple blockchains on a dapp

Tags: ethereum, solana, ethers.js, solana-web3js

I am trying to make a website that interacts with solana and ethereum blockchain, are there wallets that can handle assets on both of these blockchains and are there any libraries like phantom wallet that supports this

Answer (score 0):

You can do some of your own research, but from a quick search, the following support both Ethereum and Solana:

- Exodus
- Brave
- Torus

There's probably many others! You'll have to try out some and see.